# Google Sheets - Expand Single Date Variable into a Date Range Within A Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

Been working on a sheet that started out as a vlookup and match function but with the help of user Iamblichus grew into a script. The script pulls data from a table on Sheet1 and matches and populates it on a calendar on Sheet2. I was trying to adjust the script a little to expand on the data it pulls from Sheet1. Currently it is able to recognize a single date from Sheet1 (column b) but I'd like to be able to change that single date variable into a date range so that the value in Sheet1 column c (Length) is populated within the date range on the calendar on Sheet2.

Here's what the script currently looks like:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var firstRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet1.getLastRow() - 1;
  var firstCol = 1;
  var numCols = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  var inputData = sheet1.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  var numBrands = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var outputRange = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var outputData = outputRange.getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    for(var j = 1; j < outputData.length; j++) {
      for(var k = 1; k < outputData[0].length; k++) {
        var inputBrand = inputData[i][0];
        var outputBrand = outputData[j][0];
        var inputDate = inputData[i][1];
        var outputDate = outputData[0][k];
        if(inputBrand == outputBrand && inputDate.toString() == outputDate.toString()) {
          var inputLength = inputData[i][2];
          sheet2.getRange(j+1, k+1, 1, 1).setValue(inputLength);
        }      
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a link to my example single date sheet where the script works as intended:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13VMZJ7SZQJs8l-fJjn1RX5BVsqPY2qiS4bT_7jwmuWo/edit?usp=sharing

Here is an example of the date range I want to implement in Sheet1 and the script not working:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ie9c0AKsCA7MmYBBB81eW5BwnOM_d63kqxc2Fi3uyt8/edit?usp=sharing

I want to expand the script to be able recognize the date range set between the "Start Date" and "End Date". Then pull the value from "Length" columns in Sheet1 and fill the "Length" column value within the Date Range on Sheet2.

Comment: When I saw your shared Spreadsheet, I find the 3 columns of "Brand", "End Date", "Length" at "Sheet1". About `adding a new column for a start date`, how about reflecting to your shared Spreadsheet by you? By this, it will help users think of the solution. By the way, in your script, it seems that the OnEdit event trigger is used. But the event object is not used. So can I ask you about the method for running the script in your actual situation?

Comment: I could not even try to help you because the question it's not clear enough.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for you suggestion. I added another sheet that includes the start date column. I avoided it at first because it stops the script from working. As for the onEdit function, I added it just to run whenever an edit is detected. Have I also done this incorrectly?

Comment: @yuri apologies for lack of clarity. I've tried to clean up the question so it makes more sense. Basically, I want to expand the script to be able read the "Date range" and "Length" columns in Sheet1 and fill the "Length" column value within that date range on Sheet2.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about "Sheet2". What is the dates of "B2:BB23" in "Sheet2"? Can you provide the output you expect? And also, I cannot understand about the values of column "B" in "Sheet2". This column has no header. But the value is put. Can you explain about your goal? By the way, if you want to run the script by the OnEdit event trigger, I think that it is required to prepare the condition for running the script. Because even when one cell is edited, `onEdit()` is run. How about this?